# How to assign 0 to whole array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array. `int[] array = new int[10];`. I want to assign '0' to whole array without using loop means that 0 is to be stored in all of the indexes. How would i do it.

Answer (score 58):

After creation all items of array will have default values, which is 0 for int. So, you don't need to do anything here.

From [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx):

> The default values of numeric array elements are set to zero, and
>   reference elements are set to null.

---

Also from C# Specification [12.2 Array creation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664487%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> Elements of arrays created by array-creation-expressions are always
>   initialized to their default value.

[5.2 Default values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691171%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> For a variable of a value-type, the default value is the same as the
>   value computed by the value-type's default constructor

[4.1.2 Default constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691142%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> For sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, and ulong, the
>   default value is 0.

---

> but after assigning other values i want all the indexes to be 0 again
>   so then how would i do it?

**UPDATE:** You can use [`Array.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Sets a range of elements in the Array to zero, to false, or to null,
>   depending on the element type.

In your case:

```
Array.Clear(array, 0, array.Length);
```

Consider also to use `List<int>` instead of array - it allows to add/remove items dynamically.

Comment: yeah you are right that by default all indexes are initialized 0 but after assigning other values i want all the indexes to be 0 again so then how would i do it?

Comment: How much arrays i will create?

Comment: @Loyal if you don't want to loop, then creating new array is good option. Also consider to use `List<int>` instead of array. That will allow to clear list when you need

Comment: Does this hold true for `uint` as well?

Answer (score 27):

You don't need to do anything at all.

Since `int` is a *value type*, all elements are initilialized to `0` as a default.

From [`Arrays (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx)

> The default values of numeric array elements are set to zero, and
>   reference elements are set to null.

---

> ok if i want it to be assigned to 3 then how would i do it?

You can use for loop to assign them like;

```
int[] array = new int[10];
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    array[i] = 3;
```

If you want to give back their default values (which is `0` in this case), you can create a new array or you can use [`Array.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
Array.Clear(array, 0, array.Length);
```

If you really don't want to use any loop, you might need to use `List<int>` instead an array. It has more functionality and it creates a clean list (without any default value).

Comment: Ha-ha even same quote :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I change it with adding _at all_ so you can't blame me sir `:)`

Comment: no i am not blaming you. but i am assigning values to an array after that i want my array back to be 0. so how would i do it?

Comment: @Loyal If you want them back to zero create a new array, if you want them all to something else you need  a loop

Comment: @Loyal I didn't say it to you. It was a joke between me and Sergey. Updated my answer. Take a look.

Comment: i have mentioned in my question that without using loop. so is it possible without using loop or not?

Comment: @Loyal Updated again.

Comment: @Loyal if you want to avoid loops, Enumerable.Repeat is useful. int[] array = Enumerable.Repeat(3,10).ToArray();